# IntelliJ / Gradle - composite build project - how to import from different module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java and am currently trying to build a cucumber / selenium project in IntelliJ that contains two modules: A library project containing page definitions, and a test project that contains the cucumber features and step definitions that talk to those page definitions. The idea is that the page definitions are a shared resource, and the tests are specific to different projects / groups. Both modules are at the same level underneath the parent project. The build is using Gradle, and the `settings.gradle` file for the parent looks as follows:

```
rootProject.name = 'composite-builds'
includeBuild 'libraryproject'
includeBuild 'testproject'
```

Using Gradle `includeBuild` on the parent project works fine and the whole project imports. However I am having no luck using the library project in my import statements in the test project. It consistently returns me these kinds of error: `java: package libraryproject.pageFactory.examplePages does not exist` and is clearly not seeing the library module.

What do I need to do / add in order for the test project to recognise the library project? I did try to also add the `includeBuild` statement in the `settings.gradle` for the test project but this made no difference.

The library can be found [here](https://github.com/HesterLyonsMaru/composite-builds)

Update: the real reason that I cannot see the modules from the library project is that they were held in the test folder, not main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your **build.gradle** file

Instead of **includeBuild** use **dependencies{compile{project(':libraryproject')}}**

Inside the Root Project of libraryproject which is in your case the composite-builds. Change **includeBuild** to **include** in the **settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'composite-builds'
include ':libraryproject'
include ':testproject'
```

If it is in the same root:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
        project(':libraryproject')
    )
}
```

Subfolder:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
        project(':myFolder1:myFolder2:libraryproject')
    )
}
```

Comment: This causes the build to fail with 'Project with path ':libraryproject' could not be found in root project..., presumably because they are at the same folder level (library is not below test).

Comment: where is the library? can you give me your project structure include build.gradle location?

Comment: I have uploaded the repo to here: https://github.com/HesterLyonsMaru/composite-builds

Comment: Thank you. I think the underlying problem was that my page definitions were in test/java rather than in main/java, and hence were invisible whichever way I implemented this.